# Count the number of Wednesdays,Thursdays & Fridays in a given month

Tags: google-sheets

I need to be able to get a count of Wednesdays,Thursdays & Fridays in a given month. I've seen other posts for just Fridays in a month, however whilst testing these they have not worked. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suppose you refer to [Count the number of Fridays in a specific month](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/54798). And none of those answers work?

Comment: Yes, i'd tried a few different months and didn't get the correct total.

Answer (score 3):

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(DATE(2017,10,1),EOMONTH(DATE(2017,10,1),0),"1100011")
```

[SYNTAX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3295902)

> NETWORKDAYS.INTL(start_date, end_date, [weekend], [holidays])
>
> weekend - [ OPTIONAL - 1 by default ] - A number or string representing which days of the week are considered weekends.
>
> String method: weekends can be specified using seven 0’s and 1’s, where the first number in the set represents Monday and the last number is for Sunday. A zero means that the day is a work day, a 1 means that the day is a weekend. For example, “0000011” would mean Saturday and Sunday are weekends.